# what is the reason of BSOD: blue screen of death?- HP compaq nc6400

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bsod

I want to know what exactly causes this error in Windows?

Comment: we need more details...any recent software installs?  Driver updates? etc...

Comment: also the actual error code too.

Comment: it would be nice if you submit any further infos about the error, as chrisf suggest...also for the poor googlers out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://repairpcguide.com/the-blue-screen-of-death-and-how-to-fix-it/) for general overview.

Answer (score 1):

BSODs are caused by all kinds of things, from hardware failures to driver updates...check out this Wikipedia article on Blue Screens of Death.  highly informative...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death